# How do I pass `rails new` flags from my Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Rails application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) sound great, and I want to create my own custom template instead of repeating myself to create a common base for every single application I create.

How do I run the equivalent of `rails new --api --webpack=react --database=postgresql` from inside my template so that it automatically does this when I run `rails new myapp -m http://example.com/template.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Application template is applied **after** rails app is already generated.

What you can do is overwrite some files/lines in your application template (replace `database.yml`, etc.). Or just add those flags in the `rails new` command, along with your template parameter.

If you want to *always* create apps with those flags, just put them in the `.railsrc` file and they'll be picked up automatically.

#### ~/.railsrc

```
--api 
--webpack=react 
--database=postgresql
```

Comment: I was hoping to have a reproducible template without having a complex command to execute, but oh well. `.railsrc` it is!